# C: What is a/example of a buffer underflow?

Tags: c, underflow

I know what a *buffer overflow* is. I have no idea however what a *buffer underflow* is.

I am guessing it is when a specific buffer receives instead of an overflow of bytes, an underflow of bytes.

```
char buffer[8];
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

The above would give no error.

```
char buffer_overflow[8];
fgets(buffer_overflow, 16, stdin);
```

The above would result in a *buffer overflow* if the user input was, for example "deutschland".

Could I get an example in code, what a *buffer underflow* is?

Comment: some people decrease their pointers, instead of increasing, up to a point, underflow could happen. almost the same thing as overflow.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A buffer underflow does not relate directly to a buffer overflow. However, buffer underflows can be an issue with e.g. ring buffers.

Consider for example audio playback: your audio buffer is probably a ring buffer somewhere in kernel memory. If you write data slower than the audio driver/hardware reads from the buffer, the buffer becomes empty ("underflows"), leading to stuttering audio. Similar issues exist for other kinds of real-time data processing and media playback, too.

Thus a buffer underflow is often not a fault condition per se (unlike a buffer overflow, which usually causes programs to perform undefined, unwanted behaviour like termination, executing some unwanted code and so on).

Comment: If buffer overflows "usually" terminated programs, half of the security problems in computer systems wouldn't exist.

Comment: "Buffer underrun" is the more common term, I think.

Comment: I think both terms see plenty of usage, but "buffer underrun" might have the edge, yes.

Answer (score 7):

I have occasionally heard the term be used to refer to erroneously reading ahead of the beginning of a buffer.  I don't know whether this usage of the word is “correct”.

As an example, consider this flawed implementation of a stack.

```
struct fixed_size_stack
{
  int top;
  int data[128];
};

int
fixed_size_stack_pop(struct fixed_size_stack * this)
{
  return this->data[--(this->top)];
}
```

The missing check for `if (this->top > 0)` will cause the function to read over the lower bound of the array if a pop from an already empty stack is requested.

Comment: The usage of this word is incorrect, since what you describe is more of a buffer underread.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples in [PVS V512](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V512/). I got the issue in [gearmad](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/blob/1.1.16/libgearman-server/timer.cc#L63-L66) implementation in snippet:

```
  pollfd fds[2];
  ...
  memset(fds, 0, sizeof(pollfd));
```